# How to Generate Onlick Event Url in asp.net razor pages using tag helpers?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, window.location, tag-helpers

I have previously implemented a `onclick` event inside a `<label>` tag as shown below

```
<label onclick="window.location='/edit/@(editId)'">edit<lable>
```

but now, I want to use only tag helpers to generate links using tag helpers like `asp-page`, `asp-route-editId` etc.

how can I build above onclick url with asp-tag helpers

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you have to create the url directly, you can't use [Anchor Tag Helper attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0) because they create attributes like `href` for you. But here you have to create the link directly and use it in the `onclick` event:

if using MVC:

```
//replace ActionName and ControllerName with correct values                                     
@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName",new{editId})
```

if using Razor Page:

```
//replace id name with correct parameter name
@Url.Page("/Edit",new {id=editId })
```

Finally, your code should be as follows(*for razor page link*)

```
//replace id name with correct parameter name
<label onclick="window.location='@Url.Page("/Edit",new {id=editId })'">edit</label>
```

**One important note:**

If your input parameter name is `editid`, you can omit the parameter name in route values, but if it has a different name, for example, `itemId`, you must explicitly specify the parameter name. As follows

```
<label onclick="window.location='@Url.Page("/Edit",new {itemId = editId })'">edit</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use anchor tag helper,you need to use `<a></a>`,if you want to remove the underline and change the color,you can try to add the following styles:

```
<a asp-action="edit" asp-route-editId="1" style="color:black;text-decoration:initial">edit</a>
```

But in this way,you will have the route like:

```
https://localhost:.../edit?editId={id}
```

So that you need to change the route backend.